# How to remove object from array by property value?

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript objects:

```
var arr1 = [{id:'124',name:'qqq'}, 
           {id:'589',name:'www'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'eee'},
           {id:'567',name:'rrr'}]

var arr2 = [{id:'124',name:'ttt'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'yyy'}
```

From arr1 I need remove all objects with the same id in arr2.

Here is the desired result of arr1:

```
var arr1 = [{id:'589',name:'www'}, 
           {id:'567',name:'rrr'}]
```

What is elegant way to implement it in Javascript?

Comment: for loop would do though

Comment: `arr1[i].id === arr2[j].id ? delete(arr1[i]) : null` something on these lines would do what you need

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal The worst thing you could recommend, too bad it's even upvoted. OP don't use delete operator, this is wrong. Either find+splice or filter - are how it should be done.

Comment: if the OP is **wanting to remove the complete object** else he may set it to undefined as well

Comment: I understand what OP wants, however once again: delete operator should never be used with arrays. There going to be unwanted side effect of this.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal `filter` is the correct solution, not deleting random elements from an array.

Comment: @ssube got your point. I take my words back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to pick up the ID values on the fly. It binds the intermediate object to `this` via [the optional `thisArg` argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) of `filter`:

```js
var arr1 = [{id:'124',name:'qqq'}, 
           {id:'589',name:'www'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'eee'},
           {id:'567',name:'rrr'}];

var arr2 = [{id:'124',name:'ttt'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'yyy'}];

arr1 = arr1.filter(function (el) {
    return !this[el.id];
}, arr2.reduce(function (obj, el) {
    return obj[el.id] = 1, obj;
}, {}));

console.log(arr1);
```

The intermediate object that is passed as the last argument to `filter` looks like this:

```
{ 45: 1, 124: 1 }
```

This makes it straightforward to check if an element of `arr1` needs to be rejected or not.

Comment: no need to bind, just put `this` as [thisArg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: @NinaScholz, indeed that saves a few characters: adapted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would get a condensed list of all IDs in `arr2`, then use `indexOf` or `find` from within a `filter` to exclude those from the revised `arr1`:

```js
var arr1 = [{
  id: '124',
  name: 'qqq'
}, {
  id: '589',
  name: 'www'
}, {
  id: '45',
  name: 'eee'
}, {
  id: '567',
  name: 'rrr'
}];

var arr2 = [{
  id: '124',
  name: 'ttt'
}, {
  id: '45',
  name: 'yyy'
}];

var ids = arr2.map(function(it) {
  return it.id;
});

var unique = arr1.filter(function(it) {
  return ids.indexOf(it.id) === -1; // does not contain
});

console.log(unique);
```

If you don't want to map out the IDs -- although I would recommend doing so, since it means you don't have to walk through `arr2` repeatedly -- you can use something like:

```
var unique = arr1.filter(function(it) {
  return !arr2.some(function (other) {
    return it.id === other.id;
  });
});
```

Comment: is it possible to create it in single row?

Comment: @Michael yes, picking out the IDs ahead of time is just an optimization. I'll add an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a hash table for this.

```js
var arr1 = [{ id: '124', name: 'qqq' }, { id: '589', name: 'www' }, { id: '45', name: 'eee' }, { id: '567', name: 'rrr' }],
    arr2 = [{ id: '124', name: 'ttt' }, { id: '45', name: 'yyy' }];

arr1 = arr1.filter(function (a) {
    return !this[a.id];
}, function (hash) {
    arr2.forEach(function (a) { hash[a.id] = true; });
    return hash;
}(Object.create(null)));

console.log(arr1);
```

ES6

```js
var arr1 = [{ id: '124', name: 'qqq' }, { id: '589', name: 'www' }, { id: '45', name: 'eee' }, { id: '567', name: 'rrr' }],
    arr2 = [{ id: '124', name: 'ttt' }, { id: '45', name: 'yyy' }];

arr1 = arr1.filter((hash =>
    (arr2.forEach(a => hash[a.id] = true), a => !hash[a.id]))(Object.create(null)));
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Note that `this` is not determined by `thisArg` in arrow functions.

Answer (score -2):

I would highly encourage using [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) for this kind of object manipulation. From [the documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
var evens = _.filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
=> [2, 4, 6]
```

if you want to do the same thing on an object:

```
_.filter({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}, function(value,key){ return value % 2 == 0; })
```

In your specific case this would be the solution:

```
var newArray = _.filter(arr1,(object1) => {
    return !_.contains(_.pluck(arr2,'id'),object1.id);
});
```

This is a chart showing improvements of Underscore and Lodash on native methods:

[image]

specifically on filter it shows more than a 20% improvement.
Taken from [this article.](http://benmccormick.org/2014/11/12/underscore-vs-lodash/)

Comment: underscore is largely superflous now that `Array` has chainable functional methods. The native `filter` will work just fine for this, no need to add another (almost identical) `filter`.

Comment: Underscorejs is knows to be a lot more efficient than javascript native methods on top of being a lot cleaner. Actually for efficiency's sake I would recommend using lodash.

Comment: @NicolaPedretti *"Underscore.js is [...] a lot more efficient than javascript native methods"*: sit back and think about how underscore is implemented, namely in which language it is written. Then see how your statement could never be true.

Comment: http://benmccormick.org/2014/11/12/underscore-vs-lodash/ on top of showing underscore vs lodash shows improvements on native methods. underscore is implemented in javascript, that doesn't mean it uses built in methods...